# Select rows having not empty list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset (name of columns are just an example):

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
12   321    42  []
31   42     542 [stop]
65   64     41  []
754  76     431 [python]
```

How can I select rows having not empty list in `Col4` (i.e. second and fourth rows in the above sample)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
subdf=df[df.Col4.astype(bool)].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

could do something like this:

```
df[df['Col4'].astype(str) != '[]']
```

this just converts the column to strings to make it easier to compare an empty list

or:

```
df[df['Col4'].str.len() != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the list:

```
df = df[df['Col4'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) > 0]
```